# Junit test to fail without failure trace

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I'm running JUnit tests from Eclipse, and using the command `Assert.fail(message)` whenever I want to cause the test to fail. The problem is that I always get the message along with the entire failure trace. Is there any way for JUnit to display the message only, without the stack trace?

Comment: How do you run your test? Maven, Eclipse, standalone JUnit runner?

Comment: I'm using a test suite from Eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to crash the test without showing a long failure trace. Instead of using Assert.fail(), I create my own exception, and set the failure trace to be minimal:

```
public static void failTest(String message) throws MyTestFailure {
    System.err.println(message);
    MyTestFailure exception = new MyTestFailure(message);
    StackTraceElement elem = new StackTraceElement("com.my.package.Utils", "failTest", "failTest", 3);
    StackTraceElement elem1[] = new StackTraceElement[1];
    elem1[0] = elem;
    exception.setStackTrace(elem1);
    throw exception;
}
```

and this way I only print the message that I want to print, and a single line after that

Comment: I'm terribly confused.  If you throw your own exception from your test, but never call JUnit fail(), your test does not fail.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse JUnit settings available via *Window --> Preferences --> Java --> Junit* allow for cutting stack traces for certain exception classes:

[image: JUnit preferences]

With these settings, the stack trace for the test:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    fail("Not yet implemented");
}
```

is filtered:

[image: Filtered stack trace]

Now try to deselect the "org.junit.*" (or "junit.framework.Assert", depending which version of JUnit you're using), and rerun the test. The stack trace immediately becomes scary:

[image: Full stack trace]

Perhaps this is the feature you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If a test throws an error, the test will normally fail automatically without a message. You could of course catch Exceptions and let the test fail in the catch clause. Something like this:

```
@Test
public void test()  {
   try {
      // your test
  } catch (Exception e) {
      fail("I caught an " + e.class.getSimpleName());
   }
}
```

Of course as always when dealing with exceptions, be as precise when catching them as possible.

Comment: If a test throws an exception, then I do expect it to fail iwth the exception's data, along with the possible stack trace. But if I'm trying to force the test to fail (due to wring results, for example), using Assert.fail(message), all I want is for the test to display that message in the failure trace

Comment: Then my suggestion about catching the exception should work. I've added an example of what I mean.

Comment: This seems to give me the same behaviour as Assert.fail(). I still see the trace after the reported message

Comment: @n00bprogrammer Do you have something like `e.printStackTrace()` anywhere in the code? It seems something else than the test runner is writing output.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply override the printStackTrace()-methods for my custom Throwable:

- Exception -> ERROR
- AssertionError -> FAILURE

```java
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class TestErrorException extends Exception{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3486394019411535690L;
    private String message;

    public TestErrorException(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public void printStackTrace() {
        System.err.println(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void printStackTrace(PrintStream s) {
        s.println(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void printStackTrace(PrintWriter s) {
        s.println(message);
    }

}
```